# T-SQL: How to find and replace string patterns

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am not sure whether T-SQL supports regular expressions like other SQL engines. So far I found that I can only use PATINDEX but its matching support seems to be limited.

Here is what I want to for some field in a table using T-SQL:

- Find a substring between " IP Address: " and ","
- Replace it by " IP Address: ****,"

Here is a more concrete example:

```
SELECT some_magic("The access is from IP ADDRESS: www.xx.yyy.zz, ...")
```

I want this to return "The access is from IP ADDRESS: ****, ...".

Is it possible to do this in T-SQL? I am using Azure SQL Database.

Comment: As it is it's not clear for me, can you please provide a clear sample data and the desired results?

Comment: @Sami I tried to add a concise example. Please let me know if it is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STUFF()` and `REPLICATE()` functions as

```
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT Str,
         CHARINDEX(':', Str) +1 S,
         CHARINDEX(',', Str) -1 E
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    ('The access is from IP ADDRESS: www.xx.yyy.zz, ...')
  ) T(Str)
)
SELECT Str,
       STUFF(Str, S, (E - S)+1, REPLICATE('X', E - S)) Result
       --You could change 'X' with '*' and if you want just 4 stars then get ride of REPLICATE() and use '****'
FROM C;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d21eea60d9669060d8bd49521e308a0a)**

Comment: Good solution, and if he want to only 4 characters, he can just use '***' instead of replicate.

Answer (score 1):

@sami beat me to it. Here's what I was working on before he posted:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'The access is from IP ADDRESS: www.xx.yyy.zz, ...';

SELECT 
  [start] = fnStart.Here,
  [stop]  = fnStop.Here,
  ItemLen = fnStop.Here-fnStart.Here,
  SUBSTRING(@string,fnStart.Here,fnStop.Here-fnStart.Here),
  STUFF(@string,fnStart.Here+1,fnStop.Here-fnStart.Here-1,'****')
FROM        (VALUES('IP ADDRESS: '))                                      AS 
search(string)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(search.string,@string)+LEN(search.string))) AS fnStart(Here)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',@string,fnStart.Here+1)))               AS fnStop(Here);
```

Here's another way using [PatternSplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns). It extracts the IP address, it's length as well as returning the value you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'The access is from IP ADDRESS: www.xx.yyy.zz, ...';

SELECT
  ItemLen   = fnStop.Here-fnStart.Here,
  IPAddress = SUBSTRING(@string,fnStart.Here,fnStop.Here-fnStart.Here),
  NewString = STUFF(@string,fnStart.Here+1,fnStop.Here-fnStart.Here-1,'****')
FROM        (VALUES('IP ADDRESS: '))                                      AS search(string)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(search.string,@string)+LEN(search.string))) AS fnStart(Here)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',@string,fnStart.Here+1)))               AS fnStop(Here);
```

**Results:**

```
ItemLen     IPAddress         NewString                                   
----------- ----------------- ---------------------------------------------
14           www.xx.yyy.zz    The access is from IP ADDRESS: ****, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, the other two methods are:

```
DECLARE @START_WORD VARCHAR(100)='IP Address:'
DECLARE @END_CHAR CHAR(1)=','

DECLARE @SAMPLE AS TABLE (TEST_DATA VARCHAR(250))

INSERT INTO @SAMPLE (TEST_DATA)
VALUES ('The access is from IP ADDRESS: www.xx.yyy.zz, ...')

SELECT TEST_DATA,
REPLACE(TEST_DATA,
        (
            SUBSTRING((SUBSTRING (TEST_DATA,0,CHARINDEX(@END_CHAR,TEST_DATA))),
            CHARINDEX(@START_WORD,(SUBSTRING (TEST_DATA,0,CHARINDEX(@END_CHAR,TEST_DATA))))+LEN(@START_WORD),
            LEN((SUBSTRING (TEST_DATA,0,CHARINDEX(@END_CHAR,TEST_DATA)))))
        ),
        '****') AS EXPECTED_TEST_DATA_METHOD1,
REPLACE(TEST_DATA,
        (
            SUBSTRING ((RIGHT(TEST_DATA, LEN(TEST_DATA) - PATINDEX('%'+@START_WORD+'%', TEST_DATA)-LEN(@START_WORD) )),
            0,
            CHARINDEX(@END_CHAR,(RIGHT(TEST_DATA, LEN(TEST_DATA) - PATINDEX('%'+@START_WORD+'%', TEST_DATA)-LEN(@START_WORD) ))))
        ),
        '****') AS EXPECTED_TEST_DATA_METHOD2
FROM @SAMPLE
```